# Prove series convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^r_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers. Prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n}^r$, where $r$ is a positive integer.

I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n$ has to go to zero (why?), and in particular has to eventually be less than $1$. When you raise a number between $0$ and $1$ to a positive integer power, you get a smaller number. Put these two facts together.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Recall that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\rightarrow A$ implies
that $a_{n}\rightarrow0$. Therefore, we can find $N$ large enough
such that $a_{n}<1$ for all $n\geq N$. Therefore, we can write
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}^{r}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{n}^{r}+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}^{r}.
$$
The first sum on the right-hand side is a finite number, and hence all you need to do is show that the second sum converges to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: @Ian beat me to it. As such, please accept his answer and not mine.